# ptr to c++ source for a simple mac (cocoa) based console to use as a command interpreter

Tags: c++, cocoa, macos

I have the command language part sorted out, I'm looking for good sample on how to build a custom console in Cocoa. Need features like copy/paste, command stack, ctrl-z processsing etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want C++ source? Cocoa is much more easily accessed using Objective-C, which can be [mixed with C++](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1).

Comment: Objective-C is fine. I'm working in x-code and all my code is in C++ so far.  I'm looking for a jump start on the console UI code.  I don't have source for the console library i've been using so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the open source [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) console application, that might give you the example you want.

Comment: "jump start" is understatement. Super.  Thanks for help. -k2